# PHP - Using variables and objects within a scraper

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I'm new to PHP and have tried my best to use the PHP reference guide, but I'm clearly missing something here. Here's my workflow:

1. I have an array with about 120 links stored inside
2. I want to scrape those links and get product info from them
3. I want to store that product info in a database

For #3 I figured the best way to do this was to store the info in a PHP object, then export that to a database. Please correct me if I'm wrong and there's a better way to do this!

Here's my code, which is currently returning "PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/scriptrunner/script.php on line" errors when I try to assign the properties (weirdly, it's only when I get to property `$$productName->moreImages3 = $the_html->find(".extra_images ", 2)->src;` but this could be a red herring.

```
class Product{ //Creates an object class for products
    public $name = '';
    public $infoLink = '';
    public $description = '';
    public $mainImage = '';
    public $moreImages1 = '';
    public $moreImages2 = '';
    public $moreImages3 = '';
    public $moreImages4 = '';
    public $price = '';
    public $designer= '';
}


function getInfo($infoLink){    // Trawls the product pages for info  

    $the_content = scraperwiki::scrape($infoLink);
    $the_html = str_get_html($the_content);

    $productName = $the_html->find("#item_info h1", 0)->innertext;
    $$productName = new Product;
        $$productName->name = $productName;
        $$productName->infoLink = $infoLink;
        $$productName->designer = $the_html->find("#item_info h2", 0)->innertext;
        $$productName->description = $the_html->find("#item_info .product-body", 0)->innertext; //Might cause issues because there are multiple <p> tags in this div
        $$productName->mainImage = $the_html->find("#item_image .imagecache-product_item_default", 0)->src;
        $$productName->moreImages1 = $the_html->find(".extra_images ", 0)->src;
        $$productName->moreImages2 = $the_html->find(".extra_images ", 1)->src;
        $$productName->moreImages3 = $the_html->find(".extra_images ", 2)->src;
        $$productName->moreImages4 = $the_html->find(".extra_images ", 3)->src;
        $$productName->price = $the_html->find("#price", 0)->innertext;

        print_r($$productName ->name); //A test to see if it's working
}

for ($i = 0; $i<count($allLinks); ++$i){
   getInfo($allLinks[$i]);
};
```

The `for` loop runs through the 120 links (contained in `$allLinks`). Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

**EDIT:** For reference, there are four images on each page with class `.extra_images`, so I want to store each as a separate attribute.

Comment: Why are using two dollar symbols in front of `productName`?

Comment: Because I want the object's name to be the name of the product, which is stored in `$productName`. From what I've read, `$$productName` creates a variable whose name is the contents of `$productName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable variable names are never a good idea, especially in bulk. Just use an array:

```
$products[$productName] = new Product;
$products[$productName]->name = $productName;  
$products[$productName]->infoLink = $infoLink;
$products[$productName]->designer = $the_html->find("#item_info h2", 0)->innertext;
$products[$productName]->description = $the_html->find("#item_info .product-body", 0)->innertext; //Might cause issues because there are multiple <p> tags in this div
$products[$productName]->mainImage = $the_html->find("#item_image .imagecache-product_item_default", 0)->src;
$products[$productName]->moreImages1 = $the_html->find(".extra_images ", 0)->src;
$products[$productName]->moreImages2 = $the_html->find(".extra_images ", 1)->src;
$products[$productName]->moreImages3 = $the_html->find(".extra_images ", 2)->src;
$products[$productName]->moreImages4 = $the_html->find(".extra_images ", 3)->src;
$products[$productName]->price = $the_html->find("#price", 0)->innertext;
```

This way you can access the product individually easily by its product name like

```
echo $products[$productName]->name;
```

and also loop through all of your products if you need to:

```
foreach($products as $product)
{
    var_dump($product);
}
```

without a terrible mess.

Comment: Here's a reference on why I've done this: http://is.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: That article says sometimes its convenient - in this case it is not.

Comment: Hmm, ok, will give it a go and report back.

Comment: Made no difference - still getting `PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/scriptrunner/script.php on line 67` errors

Comment: Might be easier to just give you the link to the scraper - https://scraperwiki.com/scrapers/fashfinder/edit/# . Errors are at 66, 67, 68, all non-object. Loop runs (for two links in the array) then stops for some reason, possibly too many errors?